# Fail to install nvidia driver in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

Today I got fed up with an Xorg server crash because the driver of Nvidia was not correctly functioning, so I downloaded the latest run file from nvidia called NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.40.run
While installing this through a ssh session on my mediabox with ubuntu 16.04 installed, I ran into some errors. Apparently I had to shutdown lightdm and go to init 4 runlevel. Now I installed the run file with the command: sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.40.run --no-x-check.

With some errors the installation finished and the driver was installed. I rebooted but then Unity will not show. I blacklisted the nouveau driver and rebooten again. Same result.

When reverting to nvidia-390 driver or nvidia-415 the ubuntu desktop loads but then freezes. My wireless keyboard indicates when it's switches off and on through solaar but otherwise nothing happens. My mouse also does not work.

I tried several times purging all nvidia drivers and reverting but since the mediabox is connected to an marantz nr 1603 receiver through HDMI booting to the recovery console does not work properly.

I have a graphics card GeForce GTX 1050 Ti installed.

Comment: If I am not mistaken You should install Nvidia driver in runlevel 1. Try that.

Comment: Has sound ever worked through HDMI?

Comment: Sound has worked before through HDMI.

Comment: at runlevel 1 (command init 1 is what I did) the system return to login screen and loops. logging in does not work

Comment: In runlevel  2 the installation of the driver fails with "The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Are you sure you want to continue?"

Comment: OK, in order to make some progress I took the following steps:I have made an ssh session because the computer does not boot into the GUI

Comment: 1. Hooked up a monitorwith the on the DVI port of the videocard. I could see that the computer does not start plymouth. 2- I have made an ssh session because the computer does not boot into the GUI and upgraded from the terminal to Ubuntu 18.04.03. After the upgrade I can logon through the gui and the Nouveau driver is working. While upgrading I chose to replace the different settings files with those from the upgrade instead of keeping the old ones.